# postgresql optimize query with 'where not in' clause

Tags: postgresql, insert, performance, postgresql-performance

I have query to select all rows from table1 that they are not in tabl2 then insert them in table2.
This query is taking log time to execute since I have millions of rows in table2.

Is there better way to optimize or rewrite this query to make it execute faster.

```
WITH t1 AS (
select *
from table1
where id  not in (select id table2))
insert into table2
select * from t1 ;
```

Comment: Performance questions need to disclose a bit more information. See tag info of [\[postgresql-performance\]](https://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info)

Answer (score 3):

First you may try two things:

- Do not use WITH because it's an optimization fence. As of PostgreSQL 10, the result of the CTE query will be materialized even if it would be better not to.
- Use `NOT EXISTS` instead of `NOT IN`. Long explanation of why on stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173041/not-in-vs-not-exists

---

```
 INSERT INTO table2 
 SELECT * FROM table1
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table2 WHERE table2.id=table1.id);
```

Also, please study and share the result of an EXPLAIN of the query or if possible EXPLAIN ANALYZE.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming a `UNIQUE` index on `id` (typically the `PRIMARY KEY`), an UPSERT should be simplest - and fastest if you insert *most* of the rows:

```
INSERT INTO table2
SELECT * FROM t1
ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
```

Else, there are a couple of techniques (`NOT EXISTS` like [@Daniel demonstrates](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/196022/3684) being one of the good options):

- [Select rows which are not present in other table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363481/select-rows-which-are-not-present-in-other-table/19364694#19364694)

`NOT IN` is typically the least favorable.

Answer (score 1):

> **EXCEPT** returns all rows that are in the result of **query1** but not in
>   the result of **query2**

On the other hand, please take a loot at [EXCEPT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/queries-union.html) command as below

```
INSERT INTO table2   
SELECT * FROM table1
EXCEPT 
SELECT * FROM table2;
```